# adding a gem in gemfile causes rake db:migrate to fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake, gemfile

Summary: when I include a particular gem in Gemfile, rake db:setup no longer works; if I comment out that line in Gemfile, rake db:setup works again. Where do I look within the gem to find the problem?

Details: working on a Ruby / Rails project in cloud 9 and everything has been working fine. Then I installed the gem 'panini' - installation was successful and I am able to run test files making use of it. 'bundle show panini' shows that it is installed:

```
egr:~/workspace (add_generate_text) $ bundle show panini
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/panini-1.2.0
```

Now I want to make use of the gem within my existing project. I add the following line to Gemfile:

```
gem 'panini', '~> 1.2.0'
```

Now when I attempt rake db:setup, I get the following error:

```
egr:~/workspace (add_generate_text) $ rake db:setup
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task '' (see --tasks)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:setup => db:schema:load_if_ruby => db:create
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

If I comment out the line:

```
# gem 'panini', '~> 1.2.0'
```

then rake db:setup works again. I'm new to Rails and I think I'm missing something crucial in my understanding of how gems work; or of what rake db:setup does.

Comment: Looks like `panini` gem is not maintained for 6 years. Contact the gem author.

Comment: Gem probably doesn't support latest version of Ruby/Ruby on Rails that you are using

Comment: I'm the author.  This problem has been fixed in the latest release.

Comment: Thanks to Matthew Bellantoni who quickly responded with a fix and pushed it to Ruby gems!